# Why inline-element inside block-element create some sort of margin/padding

Tags: css

When putting inline-element inside inline-element, the child just fits correctly, for example:

```html
<span style="background-color: lightblue;">Pre <span style="background-color: tomato;">Some text</span> Next</span>
```

Thing does not go well with inline-elements being inside block elements, for example:

```html
<div style="background-color: lightblue;">Pre <span style="background-color: tomato;">Some text</span> Next</div>
```

Here if you zoom your viewport, you will notice some sort of margin/padding at the top and bottom of the child.

Can someone explain, why we get this result?

[image]

I am zooming with 500%

I also tested that with a W3School interpreter, and the problem is still

Comment: can you share screenshot with issue, not seeing any difference from the code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KKBBxaZ?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Naga Sai A, yes I will edit my question with pleasure

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Firefox

Comment: Will depend on your browser and default font-family but that's due to the `line-height: normal` default value of the parent element, which should roughly be around `1.2` on desktop (if we trust MDN). You can force it to `1` if you want it to take the whole size of your inline element, or you can set your inline element `display: inline-block` so that it grows to the parent's line height.

Comment: Thanks @ouroborus, I tested that in: firefox 107, firefox 89 and chrome 89, two computers and I got the same result, please do you zoom to 500%? because you cannot see it in normal text.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, I think the font-family used is: Time new roman, at 16 pixels, the browsers tested are above in comment, and I think you got the issue figured out, thank you mate)), i will vote you up))

Comment: I did. [Results](https://i.imgur.com/Hx2Z8JY.png)

Comment: Thanks @Ouroborus, my brain spins really fast, If we use the same browser, how can we get different results?, the problem btw, is fixed, and that's due to the line-height, but still do not know why we get two different result, anyway, thank you all for the help))